# What is the equivalent of readBigUInt64BE in java/kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, byte, biginteger, sha256

I have this snippet of javascript code:

```
crypto
    .createHash('sha256')
    .update(myString)
    .digest()
    .readBigUInt64BE();
```

And I am trying to write the same thing in kotlin.

I can get up to the `digest` part and verify the byte arrays are the same:

```
val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
val inputBytes = input.toByteArray()
val bytes = md.digest(inputBytes)
```

But I cannot seem to find an equivalent of `readBigUInt64BE` in any utility library (like `java.security.MessageDigest`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java equivalent of "BigUInt64" is an *unsigned* `long`. Java's `long` is *signed*, but can be treated as *unsigned* using the `xxxUnsigned()` methods of [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html).

Since you likely don't care about signed vs unsigned, except when printing the value, using `long` is fine. If that's not good enough, then you'd need to use `BigInteger`.

To read the value from the returned bytes from the digest, use a [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), which is similar to the Node.js [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

```java
ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getLong()
```

If the JavaScript method name had ended with "LE", you would need to specify that.

```java
ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getLong()
```

Comment: This was very close - for Kotlin specifically, however, I had to convert it to a ULong:

`ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).long.toULong()`

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, and even trying to copy the implementation of `readBigUInt64BE`, here is the solution I came up with which gives me the same result.

Kotlin:

```
private fun getHashedValue(input: String): BigInteger {
    val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
    val inputBytes = input.toByteArray()
    val bytes = md.digest(inputBytes)
    if (bytes.size < 8) { // Not sure if this case works, but I haven't hit it yet
        return BigInteger(1, bytes)
    }
    return BigInteger(1, bytes.sliceArray(0..7))
}
```

NodeJS Equivalent:

```
crypto
    .createHash('sha256')
    .update(myString)
    .digest()
    .readBigUInt64BE();
```